# MVC 3 Entitiy - Model first DB problems

Tags: c#, .net, sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting the following error when defining an association between my ExerciseSession and LatLons.

Basically i want a one- to- many relation between my:

1. asp_net_user -> exerciseSession
2. ExerciseSession -> LatLons

Is there a difference between an associations and a foreign key relation? and Can someone point to a tutorial which show how to create a 1 -> many relation in an existing .edmx Model Diagram?

Here is a picture to show everything that is going wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your foreign key have right "direction" ? From it name it looks it points from session to latlon, but from model it is obvious that it have to be in the opposite direction.

Comment: in your DB, key ExcersiseSessionTOLatLon - where it is ? to achieve one to many relation between ExcersiseSession and LatLons, it have to be in LatLon (ExcersiseSessionId, pointing to ExcersiseSession). But from its name, i tend to think, you have LatLonId in the table ExcersiseSession